# How to visible div by class by using js?

Tags: javascript

I want that if someone choose a bank from the upper options, he will be able to see the below div with bank name with options. Otherwise it should remain hidden. I have zero knowledge of javascript so need your help.

```html
<select style="border-radius: 4px;background-color:#400d48;color:white;" class="form-control">
  <option value="xxxxxx"> xxxxx</option>
  <option value="Bank"> Bank</option>
  <option value=" xxxxx"> xxxxx</option>
  <option value="xxxxxxxx"> xxxxxx</option>
</select>

<div class="sub3 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mx-2 my-2" style="text-align: left;">
  <label for="floatingPassword" class="fw-bold">Bank Name</label>
</div>
<div class="sub3 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-11">
  <select style="border-radius: 4px;background-color:#400d48;color:white;" class="form-control" name="bank_name">
    <option class="bank1" value="xxxxxxxx">BANK xxxxxxxxx</option>
    <option class="bank1" value="xxxxxxxxxxx">BANK xxxxxxxxx</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried researching and learning JavaScript? There are plenty of guides on [how to add a class to an element with JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp). The best way to learn is to do it on your own, not have others do it for you.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=show+div+select+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)